# animateWithDuration not working inside GMSMapView delegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to animate a `UIView` with the code below, but I fail to understand why the code below does not work.

**Works - `self.searchBar` animates smoothly // in all except for the said method**

```
- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView idleAtCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3
                          delay:0
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{

                         [self.searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(self.searchBar.frame.origin.x, self.searchBar.frame.origin.y - self.searchBar.frame.size.height  , self.searchBar.frame.size.width, self.searchBar.frame.size.height)];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     }];
}
```

**Does Not Work - `self.searchBar` jumps without animating**

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView willMove:(BOOL)gesture
{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.3
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{

                             [self.searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(self.searchBar.frame.origin.x, self.searchBar.frame.origin.y - self.searchBar.frame.size.height  , self.searchBar.frame.size.width, self.searchBar.frame.size.height)];

                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         }];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I opened a bug on this issue with Google (https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10349), and this was their response:

> Our understanding is that this is happening because the mapView:willMove: call is being made while already inside a CoreAnimation transaction. Our suggested work around is to wrap the UIView.animateWithDuration call within a dispatch_async back to the main thread. Something along the lines of:
>
> dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
>            // animation block here.
>         });
>
> Does that help?

Placing the UIView.animateWithDuration block inside a dispatch_async block worked for me.

Also, this question is a duplicate of [iOS layout animation ignores duration when fired on GMSMapView dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399099/ios-layout-animation-ignores-duration-when-fired-on-gmsmapview-dragging/39321995#39321995), but I don't have enough rep to flag it as such. If anyone's keeping score, it should also be noted that Google's workaround is what Vishnu suggested in his answer. I didn't have enough rep to just comment on his answer either.

Comment: You can flag after 15 rep, but you can't flag as a duplicate of an un-answered question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: Also, posting duplicate answers is a good way to get negative attention from mods.

Answer (score 1):

Use CABasicAnimation help me to solve this problem.

In my case I have to move UIView frame.

```
CABasicAnimation *moveAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"movePosition"];
moveAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake([viewToMove center].x, [viewToMove center].y)];
moveAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake([viewToMove center].x, y)];
moveAnimation.delegate = self;
moveAnimation.duration = 1.0;
moveAnimation.speed = 3.0;

moveAnimation.cumulative = YES;
moveAnimation.repeatCount = 1.0;
moveAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
moveAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
moveAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
[viewToMove.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"movePosition"];
```

Then in

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
```

save new position of `viewToMove`

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add the animation inside operation main queue:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView willMove:(BOOL)gesture
{
 [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {
        //Your animation code goes in here
    }];
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it works for me. Looks strange but it's a [GMSMapView bug](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10349)