# How can I animate NSLayoutConstraint when GMSMapView will move?

Tags: ios, animation

I want to animate buttons moving when user scrolls map (that has type `GMSMapView`) in my iOS application:

```
- (void)setButtonHidden:(bool)hidden
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        [_myButton setAlpha:hidden ? 0 : 1];
        // or so:
        [_myButtonConstraint setConstant:hidden ? -40 : 92];
        [[self view] layoutIfNeeded];
    }
}
```

Button showing animation works perfectly, but hiding is not animated.

I think than it's because of I calls `[self setButtonHidden:YES]` from `mapView:willMove:` method after which map view will be animated.

How can I combine different animations, in this case my animation and GMSMapView animation?

Comment: Did you check without alpha value?

Comment: Yes, I tried to animate moving via constraint value without alpha. I did add alpha value later for testing, but result is same - hiding doesn't animating

Comment: Set 0 instead of -40 and check, then we can find out whether its layout issue or something else? is this height layout constraint or width?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32280478) is same trouble and now I trying to resolve my problem via `CAAnimation`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution. Reason is [`GMSMapView` bug](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10349)

Solution is:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        [_myButton setAlpha:hidden ? 0 : 1];
        // or so:
        [_myButtonConstraint setConstant:hidden ? -40 : 92];
        [[self view] layoutIfNeeded];
        // or any other animation
    }];
});
```

Thanks all for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can combine animations, but `hidden` can just turn on/off.
Adjust alpha first (as you did, but not with hidden), and set hidden in completion block.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                     animations:^{
                         _myButton.alpha = hidden ? 0 : 1;
                         // or so:
                        [_myButtonConstraint setConstant:hidden ? -40 : 92];
                        [[self view] layoutIfNeeded];
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         _myButton.hidden = hidden ? YES : NO;
                     }];
```

Comment: Thanks, but result is same. Looks as `GMSMapView` interrupts my animations :(